# Add Multiple IDs in a Transaction to a LinkSet in Orientdb

Tags: database, transactions, orientdb

I'm trying to add IDs from a inserted column to another inserted column in a Transaction. I tried like this:

```
begin 
let doorOne = INSERT INTO doors SET color = green
let doorTwo = INSERT INTO doors SET color = blue
let car = INSERT INTO Cars SET doors = [$doorOne , $doorTwo]
commit retry 100
return $car
```

I get:

```
Unhandled rejection OrientDB.RequestError: The field 'Cars.doors' has been declared as LINKSET but the value is not a record or a record-id
```

I also tried to update it afterwards in the Transaction, but this won't work either (i think because the car is not created yet, so nothing to update) and i dont want to do it in two different calls, if there is a way to do it in one Transaction.

Comment: The error says "car.doors", but your class is "Cars" (look at the `insert into`).

Comment: Sorry, was just an example i made up. Was a typo, changed it

Answer (score 1):

This is because INSERT returns, by default, the number of inserted entries. Try adding this clause at the end of each INSERT statement: `RETURN @rid`